# True or False: A rectangle is square if and only if its main diagonals are equal.

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, logic

My textbook says this is true, but I disagree. First of all, it should be written that the diagonals are *congruent*, not *equal*, yes? Assuming they meant congruent, this is what I have tried:

Conditional:

"If a rectangle is square, then its main diagonals are equal" is (True) because this is true of all rectangles.

Conversely:

"If a rectangle's diagonals are equal, then it is a square" is (False) because there exists a rectangle that is not a square that has equal diagonals.

Am I right on this?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: What textbook is this?  Of course the two diagonals in any rectangle have the same length...did they really claim otherwise?

Comment: The justification given:

A rectangle is a square if and only if its main diagonals are equal.
True. The main diagonals of a square are equal, and if the main diagonals
are equal then it is a square

Comment: What is true is that, if the diagonals of a *rhombus* are congruent, then it is a square.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this was unusual. I think it was written by the professors (I'd rather not say which at this time). Must have been an oversight.

Comment: This is true because for every rectangle the diagonals are "congruent" (equal is good because it is length) and a square is a rectangle where all its sides are equal. It is true but meaningless.

Comment: @Moti, This is an if-and-only-if problem. The first direction is true, but the converse is false, making the whole statment false.

Comment: It is not clear why you interpret this as if-and-only-if.